# Python Serial Connections with Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python, function, tkinter, pyserial

I am trying to make a GUI for a serial project, and I need to be able to select a comm port and run commands using the comm port.

Here is an example of the GUI I want, in a table form.

```
Start Connection | Dropdown of Comm Numbers | Button to run commands
```

I have some code that I have been working on, but this is leaving me pretty stumped.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import ctypes
from functools import partial

def connect(ser):    #button that starts a connection, ser
    try:
        port = D.get()    #snags the number in the dropdown
        print(D.get())
        ser = serial.Serial(
                        port = "COM" +str(port),
                        baudrate=9600,
                    )
        print(ser.port)
    except:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Fail", title, 0)
        ser.close()
    return ser

def running(ser):    #button that runs a ton of commands through ser
    P['value']=0
    ser.write(b'lottsacommands')
    P['value']=100
    root.update_idletasks()

root = tk.Tk()
bottomframe = Frame(root)    #frame for bottom of root window
bottomframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

D = StringVar(bottomframe)
P = Progressbar(bottomframe,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100,mode='determinate')  #build a progress bar in the window 'P'
B = tk.Button(bottomframe,text='Begin Run In',command=partial(running, ser))     #build the button 'B'
B2 = tk.Button(bottomframe,text="Connect To Serial",command=partial(connect, ser))
T2 = tk.Text(bottomframe, height=1, width=7)    #box that says comm

P.pack()    #pack progress bar
B.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)       #formats the button
B2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
T2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)       #format the ports dropdown

ports = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
DR = OptionMenu(bottomframe, D, *choices)   #creates the dropdown
DR.pack()

T2.insert(tk.END, 'COMM')    #makes the box say comm
tk.mainloop()    #runs the loop
```

I just can't seem to get the comm port connection in the connection function to carry over to the second executing function. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your posted code failed to compile because `ser` is not defined.  Also `*choices` should be `*ports` in `DR = OptionMenu(..., *choices)`.  The `return ser` statement is useless in `connect()` function as its return value has not been used in your code.

Comment: So, if I define ser early in the code, like `ser = 1`, the return statement will change the value of ser so that the next function can use it?

Comment: No because the `ser` in `connect()` function is a local variable.  You need to declare it as global inside `connect()`.  As I said before, `return ser` is useless in this case as there is no receiver of the return.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I was able to fix this by using a global variable for ser, so that it was carried outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I did not have ser defined globally. I changed the connect function so that the ser it created was no longer local to the function but global, overwriting the 1 that ser is initialized with.

```
def connect(ser):    #button that starts a connection, ser
    try:
        global ser        #makes ser a global variable accessible to other functions
        port = D.get()    #snags the number in the dropdown
        print(D.get())
        ser = serial.Serial(
                        port = "COM" +str(port),
                        baudrate=9600,
                    )
        print(ser.port)
    except:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Fail", title, 0)
        ser.close()
    return ser
```